# How to handle topic changes in comments?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138461/if-success-prompt-alert-instead-of-echo-how/12138555#comment16239142_12138555).

It's a new question I think and I don't see why not to answer it. But it only came up in the discussion. Is there a "right" way to handle this?

Comment: see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: @Jens I feel your pain. It irks me when that happens because then the `new` question is answered in the comments, which are basically white noise after the 8th or so post.